# .Net Core Windows Authentication, Authorize Access to Specific AD Group

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-authentication

I am building an Angular frontend and .Net 5 backend app. I have configured the app with following lines for windows authentication.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization();
```

I have also enabled windows authentication in IIS directly.

I can see a windows popup coming and I can login with my domain account.

Questions:

- If I have enabled windows authentication in code, then why I need to do that through IIS?
- web.config generated by IIS in .net core app does not have anything related to authentication. why is that? If I disabled windows and enable anonymous authentication, web.config is not getting updated.
- I want to give access to users for a specific AD group to view the website. How can I do that with angular frontend? Just to test that, I have created a local group on the server where app is hosted and given that group read permissions on the folder in IIS app. I have added a test user in that group. After this setting, I should not be able to login but I can still login.

App is hosted on Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10

Comment: any help please?

Comment: any help please?